# How should i send file of my own format with email and what should i do to be able to open it in my own application in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, mime-types

I am sending my file using MIME-type "application/tfk" and i wrote this in my Info.plist :

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>tfk</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>application/tfk</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.dmm.tfk</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

but it is not working. My application is not on the list in Mail app. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to declare a UTI as well.  Here is the documentation on [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html).

Here is an example of what you should add:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>My document</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.dmm.tfk</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>tfk</string>
                    <string>TFK</string>
                </array>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/tfk</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Not sure if that is all you need, but once you have it working, it will send launchOptions to your AppDelegate.  The file URL will be sent as the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key in `launchOptions` on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your `AppDelegate`.  You can then pull the file data from that URL using: `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:`.  Hope that helps!